# Better option to store latitude and longitude on Postgres

Tags: postgresql, performance, datatypes

I'm adding a GIS module to my Proyect, then I need o store latitude and longitude into my Postgres Database(table target has 500,000 registers by now).

For example:

```
latitude = 40.767504
langitude = -73.974716
```

I'm not sure what DataType would be better(performance) to use: decimal with 6 decimal points, String or another.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A [point](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-geometric.html#id-1.5.7.16.5)?

Comment: I'm not an expert on PostgreSQL, but I would recommend researching the performance of the point data type (especially in an index) compared to decimal. While it appears to be logically the most convenient for your use case (and I think cool that they offer it as a data type) sometimes the most logically fitting solution isn't the most performant fitting, which it seems like what your primary concern is in your question.